# Is `TABLE()` a function, an explicit type conversion operator (like in C), or something else?

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL, when defining a function which returns a table,

```
CREATE FUNCTION sum_n_product_with_tab (x int)
RETURNS TABLE(sum int, product int) AS $$
    SELECT $1 + tab.y, $1 * tab.y FROM tab;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

What is `TABLE()`?
Is `TABLE()` a builtin function, an explicit type conversion operator (like in C), or something else?

Is `return table` a inseparable command, just as `create table` is? In PostgreSQL's document, why does ["SQL Commands"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-commands.html) list `CREATE TABLE` but not `RETURN TABLE` or `RETURN`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a function, it's just a syntax element stating that the function returns a "table" and name the columns of that table. Similar to the part after `create table`.

When you write `create table person(id integer, name text);` you don't expect `person()` to be a function, do you?

This let's you define functions returning sets without having to predefine the type up-front as you need with `returns setof ...`

`returns table()` is not listed as a separate [SQL Command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html) because it is not a "SQL command". It is a syntax element that is *part* of the `create function` command. It can't be used anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks. Is `return table` a inseparable command, just as `create table` is? In PostgreSQL's document, why does ["SQL Commands"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-commands.html) list `CREATE TABLE` but not `RETURN TABLE` or `RETURN`?

Comment: The SQL commands page cover the more basic ANSI SQL standards and some PostgreSQL extensions on those ANSI SQL standards @Ben

Comment: @RaymondNijland Is `return table` not a command in either basic ANSI SQL standards or PostgreSQL extensions?

Comment: "There is another way to declare a function as returning a set, which is to use the syntax RETURNS TABLE(columns). This is equivalent to using one or more OUT parameters plus marking the function as returning SETOF record (or SETOF a single output parameter's type, as appropriate). This notation is specified in recent versions of the SQL standard, and thus may be more portable than using SETOF." source https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/xfunc-sql.html @ben looks like `RETURN TABLE` is a SQL standard.. Then i don't know why it's not on the SQL commands page..

Comment: @Ben: no, it's not a "command". If it was, it would be listed in [SQL Commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html) - it's part of the syntax for `create function` just like e.g. `on (column1)`  is part of a `create index` - do you think `ON ()` is a separate command?